# powerpivot results from two DBs into a single table

Tags: sql-server, powerpivot

I  have a query that unions the results from two different DBs on the same server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        DB1.Table1.ProjectName ,
        CAST(DB1.Table1.ProjectFinishDate AS DATE) AS 'FinishDate' ,
        DB1.Table1.ProjectOwnerName AS 'ProjectOwner'
FROM    DB1.Table1 
WHERE   DATEDIFF(MONTH,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,DB1.Table1.ProjectFinishDate) < 7
        AND DB1.Table1.ProjectPercentCompleted < 100
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT
        DB2.Table1.ProjectName ,
        CAST(DB2.Table1.ProjectFinishDate AS DATE) AS 'FinishDate' ,
        DB2.Table1.ProjectOwnerName AS 'ProjectOwner'
FROM    DB2.Table1 
WHERE   DATEDIFF(MONTH,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,DB2.Table1.ProjectFinishDate) < 7
        AND DB2.Table1.ProjectPercentCompleted < 100
ORDER BY CAST(Table1.ProjectFinishDate AS DATE)
```

The query works fine in SQL, but I need to present the results in Excel as a single table. Because it's in two different DBs, however, I can't get it to work as the output of a single Data Connection. I'm trying to pull the output into PowerPivot because it seems like that should allow me to do this, but I can't get it to work there either.

Can someone tell me if there's a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If this is just a one time thing, I would just run the query in SSMS and copy the resultset into Excel and turn it into a pivot table.

Comment: Good point, should have called out that this will be a live report that will be accessed on a regular basis. Otherwise, yeah, a quick copy and paste would do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully this helps!

[Combining Data from Multiple Relational Data Sources into One Table in PowerPivot for Excel](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2893/combining-data-from-multiple-relational-data-sources-into-one-table-in-powerpivot-for-excel/)

Comment: Weird - I'd actually already tried to just copy my UNION query into the PowerPivot table design window, and it choked. I tried it again, based on your link, and now it worked great.

Thanks, appreciate the assistance.

Comment: Glad to know it helped! I have worked with Excel quite extensively before but never had to pull data from two different database. That's quite interesting!

Comment: If you could do me a favor, please upvote my answer, I am just 3 points short reaching a milestone here. :) Not that it matters, but that would help. Thanks!